# How do I read a text file image and save it to an array?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I have to write a program which reads in a text binary image 1's and 0's and then perform various operations on the image depending on the users choice. I believe I am quite fine with the majority of the program, I am able to read in the file and display it. **In order to proceed, I need to save the image to a 2D array, and this is what I am stuck with.**

Below is a small sample of my whole program as the rest of it currently works, this is the bit I am trying to figure out, but after continued searching and videos, I cannot for the life of me figure this out or where I am going wrong.

```
#define N 50
int imageArray [N][N];
int row, col;
int value;
char filename[30];
FILE *ptr_file;
printf("Enter the full name of the input file: ");
scanf("%s", filename);

ptr_file = fopen(filename, "r");

for(row = 0; row < N; row++){
    for(col = 0; col < N; col++){
        fscanf(ptr_file, "%d", &value);
        imageArray[row][col] = value;
    }

}

for(row = 0; row < N; row++){
    for(col = 0; col < N; col++){
        printf("%d", imageArray[N][N]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The images I'm trying to save to the 2D array are all 50x50 and contained in the txt files.

The code above currently outputs all 0's. The background of the image is made up of 0's while the image itself is made up of 1's.

Below is a **super small version** of what I am trying to save to the array, imagine it as a 50x50! I just couldn't paste the full image here for some reason because it reformatted it. It should give an idea though.

```
0000000
0001000
0011100
0111110
0011100
0001000
0000000
```

Thanks in advance for the reading the post!

Comment: Does `fscanf("%1d", ...)` or `fgetc(...) - '0'` work? Normally the `%d` format will go as far as it can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

1. As Mike P stated you should uses "%1d" with fscanf(), otherwise each fscanf() call will read the entire line as it will continue reading until the end of the first series of numeric characters with "%d".
2. Your print loop is printing `imageArray[N][N]` instead of `imageArray[row][col]`.

With both of these fixes implemented I got the code to run as expected.

```
int imageArray [N][N];
int row, col;
int value;
char filename[30];
FILE *ptr_file;
printf("Enter the full name of the input file: ");
scanf("%s", filename);

ptr_file = fopen(filename, "r");

for(row = 0; row < N; row++){
    for(col = 0; col < N; col++){
        fscanf(ptr_file, "%1d", &value);
        imageArray[row][col] = value;
        printf("%d %d\n", row, col);
    }

}

for(row = 0; row < N; row++){
    for(col = 0; col < N; col++){
        printf("%d", imageArray[row][col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

As an additional note you should check the return of fscanf() to ensure that the call succeeded.  If you did that with your original code it would have given you a good hint to the location of the first error.  It may also be used to detect an invalid input file.

Comment: That worked! This is such a relief! the "%1d" is something I will note for future use! Thanks for spotting the imageArray[N][N] "human error"!

Comment: Yeah, I realised if I simply entered diamond as the input, it would display just a background of 0's but if I entered the full file name Diamond.txt, it will then display the full image. So I will be sure to provide a way to check that the correct file name is being entered.